# Windows Server 2016 run unsigned driver

Tags: driver, signature, windows-server-2016

I use a Windows Server 2016 and want to test my driver. I add keys

```
 bcdedit /set testsigning on
```

And after that, I reboot my system and choose "disable driver signature enforcement" mode.

I launch my driver via OSR driver loader. I receive a successful message box that my driver has been installed and launched. But in a moment the message:"A digitally signed driver is required".

I also tried the commands:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
bcdedit.exe /set nointegritychecks on
```

How can I disable signature verification? I've tested it on Windows 10 1511 and there is no problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
bcdedit /set loadoptions DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
```